# How to search in a dictionary when key is of type tuple?

Tags: c#, dictionary

Suppose we have a dictionary like this:

```
Dictionary<Tuple<Foo, Bar>, Baz> dictionary;
```

1. How can we find if there is any item with `foo` as a part of its key?
2. How can we find all values with `foo` as part of their keys?

I can do it using for loops like:

```
foreach(var pair in dictionary)
    if (pair.Key.Item1.IsEqual(foo))
    { set flag and break / add pair.Value to the list }
```

, but I thought there must be some one-lined code for that.

Comment: `bool result = dictionary.Any(pair => pair.Key.Item1.IsEqual(foo);`

Comment: A dictionary does not have a "give me all keys/key-value-pairs where *part* of the key matches". You will have to use normal collection-based LINQ operators which will enumerate over them all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When querying, try using Linq:

```
using System.Linq;

... 

// If we have at least one record?
bool result = dictionary.Any(pair => pair.Key.Item1.IsEqual(foo));
```

All such records:

```
var result = dictionary.Where(pair => pair.Key.Item1.IsEqual(foo));
```